# How to resize a binary image through scikit-image?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have an image represented in an array such that its shape is `(128,128)` and the data type is `bool` (which means it represents a binary image).

So I need to resize it to a given scale (say, `(543, 347)`).

Can anyone tell me a way to do this easily using python's `scikit-image` library?

Comment: You want to pad the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`resize`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) and [`img_as_bool`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html#skimage.img_as_bool) to get the job done.

#### Demo

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import img_as_bool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bool_arr = np.zeros(shape=(128, 128), dtype=np.bool)
bool_arr[32:96, 32:96] = True
resized = img_as_bool(resize(bool_arr, (543, 347)))

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(bool_arr, cmap='gray')
ax0.set_title('Boolean array')
ax1.imshow(resized, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_title('Resized')
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks a ton, great answer

Comment: You don't need to convert the image. `skimage.transform.resize` has parameter `order`. Just use `0`, instead of default `1`. [Here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp) you can read about available methods.

Comment: hi. what if in the above code I want to increase and decrease the size of the mask as per the user's request?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with skimage.transform.resize library.
read the image and resize.

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
img = io.imread(path/to/the/image)
image_resized = resize(img, (543, 347),anti_aliasing=True)
image_resized.show()
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: can you tell me what img.shape() prints?

Comment: it prints `(128, 128)`

Comment: I'm not getting the image from `imread()` function, it's just a an array having values of the type `boolean`

Comment: now again try this edited code. I guess you are not showing the image.Try showing using imgfilename.show()

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pad your image? Try:

```
skimage.util.pad
```

Wich will preserve initial dimensions, and then try a

```
skimage.util.crop
```

Keep in mind that this might affect operations/predictions etc. So might have to append NaN to mitigate.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html)

Comment: this is right. but the problem is I have `boolean` values inside the image matrix, I think this is the main point of this question

Comment: You can choose the padding, just pad with 0s or NaNs, boolean values make no difference